# Multiple thread processing the same data simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new to multithreading and am missing the right jargon. Would be great to have some pointers to how to start.

I would like to have a main thread that is continuously checking for new data. Once new data arrives it should distribute to n worker nodes. Each worker node has a different setting but all worker nodes should process the **same** data simultaneously and then wait for new data being provided by the main thread.

Not sure this works with queues? Since a worker would remove the item from the queue and the others would not process any item.

Then maybe a global variable or using the shared memory space?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use n queues, 1 for each worker?

Comment: I suppose that would work and push the new data into each queue. good idea